# Visual Studio Code window has crashed

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm getting the below error in visual studio code:

[image: visual studio error]

When I click on reopen this alert kept coming and not allowing me to write the code inside the editor. I have uninstall and reinstall visual studio code but still its showing this error.

Comment: One thing that's worked for me is deleting the folder (first check if you have anything important there)  in C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try terminating any Code.exe processes still alive in Task Manager

Comment: Also, any other forked process like code analyzers should also be killed.

Comment: Cmd-Option-Escape, pick it from the list and Force Quit

Answer (score 7):

**Mac only:**

```
$ open /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app -n
```

For context:
`-n, --new Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running.` Thanks @TMG. More options can be found in the docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

[image: VS Code documentation]

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!
For anyone wondering what `-n` does, here is what help says:
`-n, --new         Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running.`

Answer (score 3):

I have VS Code v1.38.1 installed on Ubuntu 18.4
encounter a similar crashing issue (failed to launch Code) today.
It is possibly due to Ubuntu stopped while Code was open.

To resolve this issue, I did the following

```
  $ cd ~/.config/Code
  $ rm -rf Cache/
  $ rm -rf CacheData/
  $ rm -rf CacheExtensions/
```

Comment: I just had this issue for the past couple of days on VS Code 1.77.2 and 1.77.3 on Pop OS (Ubuntu based) 22.04.


Clearing out `~/.config/Code/CachedExtensions` and `~/.config/Code/CachedData` did the trick. (I then relaunched VS Code with `code -n` as mentioned in other answers)

Answer (score 2):

Run this code on your ubuntu terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/Code/
```

I am not sure it works for other Operating system

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio Code** states probable reason for that:
[image]